# Move a div that's outside the body tag to inside body tag

Tags: wordpress, html, plugins, move

I have a wordpress plugin that puts social icons at the top of my website. The problem is though the div is outside the main body div (or wrap div). Therefore, when I change the width of my site the social icons move relative to the browser window and not no the actual content of my website. Normally it would be as simple as just moving that div outside the wrap div to inside it, but it is a plugin and the structure of the plugin is nasty in that the div structure is in a minified javascript file and not in a nice HTML/PHP format.

So if you go to my site: http://warringah-plastics.com.au/ you can see the social icons in the div "dcsmt" in the top right hand corner and I want to position it to the left of the website search box where those existing social icons are. How would I do this? So I really want to put the "dcsmt" div inside the existing "top-cont" div. Thanks!

Comment: You could change that div's location in the DOM using some simple javascript. I'd think.

Answer (score 0):

Create an empty div and give it a name "social_icons_wrapper" in your header near the search box where you want the social media icons.

Then call the following javascript from your footer:

```
var div_to_move = document.getElementById('dcsmt');
document.getElementById('social_icons_wrapper').appendChild(div_to_move);
```